# Error when closing remote desktop connection

Tags: mstsc

Every time I close a remote desktop connection to a specific machine an error occurs. I get the following error message:

---

Remote Desktop Connection has stopped working

A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

---

To be clear, i have no trouble connecting and working on the remote machine using remote desktop. It is just annoying that an error occurs everytime i close the connection. Also this only happens on one specific machine, i can connect to many other machines and close them without errors.

The error also only occurs on one machine only. Creating a remote desktop connection to the machine from another machine and closing is does not result in an error.

OS Machine on which the error occures: Windows 10

OS Remote machine: Windows 2016

Any thoughts on how to solve this error?

Comment: Any logoff script or such that could potentially block the rdp service on the host when you quit ?

Comment: No, no logoff or login scripts